# In Python, what is the difference between f.readlines() and list(f)

Tags: python, list, file, file-io, python-internals

From both [Python2 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and [Python3 Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), there is a line in the midpoint of *section 7.2.1* saying:

> If you want to read all the lines of a file **in a list** you can also use `list(f)` or `f.readlines().`

So my question is: What is the difference between these two ways to turn a file object to a list? I am curious both in performance aspect and in underneath Python object implementation (and maybe the difference between the Python2 and Python3).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference; both methods result in the exact same list.

Implementation wise, one uses the file object as an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) (calls `next(f)` repeatedly until `StopIteration` is raised), the other uses a dedicated method to read the whole file.

Python 2 and 3 differ in what that means, exactly, unless you use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) in Python 2. Python 2 file objects [use a hidden buffer for file iteration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next), which can trip you up if you mix file object iteration and `.readline()` or `.readlines()` calls.

The `io` library (which handles all file I/O in Python 3) does not use such a hidden buffer, all buffering is instead handled by a [`BufferedIOBase()` wrapper class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase). In fact, the [`io.IOBase.readlines()` implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c96af2fba28/Modules/_io/iobase.c#l585) uses the file object as an iterator under the hood *anyway*, and [`TextIOWrapper` iteration delegates to `TextIOWrapper.readline()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8c96af2fba28/Modules/_io/textio.c#l2497), so `list(f)` and `f.readlines()` essentially are the same thing, really.

Performance wise, there isn't really a difference even in Python 2, as the bottleneck is file I/O; how quickly can you read it from disk. At a micro level, performance can depend on other factors, such as if the OS has already buffered the data and how long the lines are.