# Python: How to replace the last word of a line from a text file?

Tags: python

How would I go about replacing the last word of a specific line from all the lines of a text file that has been loaded into Python? I know that if I wanted to access it as a list I'd use [-1] for the specific line, but I don't know how to do it as a string. An example of the text file is:

```
A I'm at the shop with Bill.
B I'm at the shop with Sarah. 
C I'm at the shop with nobody. 
D I'm at the shop with Cameron.
```

Comment: `line.split()[-1]` gives you the last word of a string of words

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have blank lines, you might want to try [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines)

```
lines = your_text.splitlines()
lastword = lines[line_to_replace].split()[-1]
lines[line_to_replace] = lines[line_to_replace].replace(lastword, word_to_replace_with)
```

keep in mind that your changes are in `lines` now and not `your_text` so if you want your changes to persist, you'll have to write out `lines` instead

```
with open('shops.txt', 'w') as s:
    for l in lines:
        s.write(l)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "write out `lines` instead?

Comment: when you split `your_text` it is being stored in a new object `lines`.  You can use `lines` all you want, but your original text `your_text` is not modified.

Comment: I see. How do I modify it then?

Comment: The `lines` object will be an updated version of the `shops.txt` file.  You can simply just overwrite the original file with data in `lines`.  If the `shops.txt` file is really big, then you're going to have to switch to a WAY more complicated solution.

Comment: The way I've done it in my edited post, I'm trying to overwrite it but it just overwrites the entire file with the single edited line.

Comment: That's because you're only writing the one line to the file.  You have to write *every* line back as you're overwriting the contents of the file.  When you open the file as `w` you're truncating (emptying) the file before you start filling it.  Then you're only writing that single line to the file (thus, why you need to write like the loop in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more powerful editing option, Regex is your friend.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\w*(\W*)$')  # Matches the last word, and captures any remaining non-word characters
                                    # so we don't lose punctuation. This will includes newline chars.

line_num = 2 # The line number we want to operate on.
new_name = 'Steve' # Who are we at the shops with? Not Allan.

with open('shopping_friends.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines[line_num] = re.sub(pattern, new_name + r'\1', lines[line_num]) 
    # substitue the last word for your friend's name, keeping punctuation after it.
    # Now do something with your modified data here
```

Comment: Yep. Retention of punctuation and whitespace is important, and regex is easier than trying to replace the last word without disturbing the rest of the line by using string functions.

Answer (score 0):

please check this , is not 100% pythonic, is more for an overview

```
file_text = '''I'm at the shop with Bill.
I'm at the shop with Sarah. 
I'm at the shop with nobody. 
I'm at the shop with Cameron.
I'm at the shop with nobody.'''

def rep_last_word_line(textin, search_for, replace_with, line_nr):
    if (isinstance(textin,str)):
        textin = textin.splitlines()
    else:
        # remove enline from all lines - just in case
        textin = [ln.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '') for ln in textin]
    if (textin[line_nr] != None):
        line = textin[line_nr].replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')

        splited_line = line.split()
        last_word = splited_line[-1]
        if (last_word[0:len(search_for)] == search_for):
            splited_line[-1] = last_word.replace(search_for,replace_with)
        textin[line_nr] = ' '.join(splited_line)

        return '\r\n'.join(textin)

print rep_last_word_line(file_text,'nobody','Steve',2) 
print '='*80
print rep_last_word_line(file_text,'nobody','Steve',4) 
print '='*80
# read content from file

f = open('in.txt','r')
# file_text = f.read().splitlines() # read text and then use str.splitlines to split line withoud endline character
file_text = f.readlines() # this will keep the endline character 
print rep_last_word_line(file_text,'nobody','Steve',2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a file "example.txt":

```
with open("example.txt") as myfile:
   mylines = list(myfile)
   lastword = mylines[2].split()[-1]
   mylines[2] = mylines[2].replace(lastword,"Steve.")
```

(Edit: fixed off by one error... assuming by 3rd line, he means human style counting rather than zeroth-indexed)

(Note that the with line returns a file object which will be automatically closed even if for example the length of myfile is less than 3; this file object also provides an iterator which then gets converted into a straight list so you can pick a specific line.)

Comment: it's interesting, what is more pythonic - type casting as like list(myfile) or myfile.readlines function?

Comment: I would argue the myfiles.readlines function is more pythonic.  I see Typecasting as very rare, and the readlines() method is there for that specific reason.

Comment: this solution will work fine with OP data, but will fail for string like "I'm at the shop with Steve and Steve"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958198/in-python-what-is-the-difference-between-f-readlines-and-listf covers that question as far as perf etc. (but I didn't really see any clear arguments for one or the other)... there is also a link for readlines considered silly